# I have set a style of title using titlesec, however it has started displaying a "zero" on the table of contents page

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I have set a title style using the titlesec package however this code now displays a zero next to the "contents" title on the table of contents page. How do I remove this ?
I also would like to know how to number the page before the table of contents in roman numerals except for the cover page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}
\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1cm}
            
            {\LARGE \textbf{Thesis title}}
            
            \vspace{1cm}
            {\Large subtitle}
            
            \vspace{1.5cm}
            
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{universitylogo.png}
            
            \vspace{1cm}
            Bachelor's Thesis
            
            \vspace{1cm}
            subtitle
            
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            semester year
            
            \vspace{1cm}
            {\Large name}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    \noindent \hspace{-0.5cm}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{universitylogo}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \noindent degree \hspace{5.4cm} Abstract
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    \noindent Author: \hspace{0.8cm} name \hspace{6.7cm} Year 2021
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \noindent Subject: \hspace{0.7cm} thesis title
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \noindent Supervisors: \hspace{0.0cm} supervisor name
    
    \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \noindent text
    \newpage
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        
        {\Huge \textbf{Acknowledgments, Dedication, and Declaration}}
        
    \end{center}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \noindent {\large \textbf{Acknowledgments:}}
    \newline thanks
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    \noindent {\large \textbf{Dedication:}}
    \newline
    To my \textbf{thanks}
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    \noindent {\large \textbf{Declaration:}}
    \newline
    declaration
    
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{chapter1}
    \input{chapterlocation/chapter1.tex}
    \chapter{chapter2}
    \input{chapterlocation/chapter2.tex}
    \chapter{chapter3}
    \input{chapterlocation/chapter3.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image: need to remove the zero]

Comment: Provide complete code to understand your problem better.

Comment: @mmr How much more do you need, as more code would reveal my thesis.

Comment: @mmr done provided as much as I could .

Comment: Add to your formatting the format of unnumbered chapters, such as the table of contents or the bibliography  with this code: `\titleformat{name=\chapter,` `numberless}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `block` mode rather than `display` and set the number in the appropriate argument to `\titleformat`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  width=150mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  bindingoffset=6mm,
  showframe, % to see the boundaries
]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}
  {\thechapter.}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Remove the `showframe` option for the production version. I only included what's really necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Bernard has said
I added the line;

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
```